# How to Make a certain Div ID show at and after a different Div ID with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a jQuery code so that my Menu will be hidden on the top section of a page and appear when it is at or past a certain div ID. I have written what I best can to achieve this but is not working. Can anyone help me configure it properly? Thank you.

```
jQuery (function($){
var topHeader = $('#top-header');
var mainSlider = $('#pbf-main-slider');
    if (topHeader >= mainSlider) {
        topHeader.show();
    } else {
        topHeader.hide();
    }

});
```

menu hidden area

[image]
menu show area

[image]

Final Outcome (I added another section of the menu that needed this function)

```
    jQuery (function($){
var topHeader = $('#top-header');
var mainHeader = $('#main-header');
var mainSlider = $('#pbf-main-slider');
var mainSliderHeight = mainSlider.outerHeight(true);
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(); //get the scroll position
    if (scrollTop >= mainSliderHeight) {
        topHeader.slideDown(1000);
        mainHeader .slideDown(1000);
    }
    else {
        topHeader.hide(500);
        mainHeader .hide(500);
    }
})
});
```

Comment: object >= object ? You mean height or something that. Pls post any picture what you want to do. Ty

Comment: Hello, thank you for the quick response. I added some pictures explaining how I want to menu hidden before a certain DIV ID and to appear after that same DIV ID. Hopefully this helps. Let me know, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get the height of the main slider, like this:

```
var mainSlider = $('#pbf-main-slider');
var mainSliderHeight = mainSlider.outerHeight(true);
```

then make the top bar appear if the scroll is past the mainSlider's height, like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(); //get the scroll position
    if (scrollTop >= mainSliderHeight) {
        topHeader.show();
    }
    else {
        topHeader.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried writing out the code as shown below. However the menu only stays hidden no matter where I am on the screen.                 
jQuery (function($){
var topHeader = $('#top-header');
var mainSlider = $('#pbf-main-slider');
var mainSliderHeight = mainSlider.outerHeight(true);
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); //get the scroll position
    if (scrollTop >= mainSliderHeight) {
        topHeader.show();
    } else {
        topHeader.hide();
    }
});

Comment: @Publifiedlabs sorry i forgot to wrap everything inside a scroll listener, check the edit!

Comment: also i suggest addign and removing a class from your top header so you can animate it with css to make it look smoother than a simple hide/show.

Comment: Hello, I got it to work! Thank you so much for your help. instead of the show function I changed it to a slideDown animation to give it some style. I will update the post with the final code for others that may have this issue. Thank you again!

Comment: @Publifiedlabs Glad it worked :) an upvote would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello, I pressed the green check mark and clicked the up arrow. Hope I did it right! Sorry I am new to stackoverflow.